# How do I access AntiForgery.GetTokens() in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, csrf

The tutorial [Preventing CSRF](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) by Mike Wasson, introduces a method called GetTokens() that is supposed to reside within the System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery class (as confirmed on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery.gettokens%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)).

I am using ASP.NET 4.0, C#, and MVC 3 and cannot find this method anywhere. It doesn't exist, and the MSDN page about the method doesn't not give any hints as to which version of the framework contains the GetTokens() method. Am I missing something? I left a comment on Mike Wasson's post, but he apparently doesn't read the comments there (at least not anymore) because I'm the second person to raise the question there and there are no responses.

Where can I find this method?

Answer (score 1):

This method (as well as HttpRequestMessage class itself) is new to .NET 4.5. You most likely using an older version of this framework. But you can still manually iterate through the headers and check if the specific header is present.